# Make a div clickable to dynamic link from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to create a div with news articles and need my div to send the user to the new page referenced by the provided link from my JSON file. My issue is how can I properly reference the link from the JSON file, so when the json file updates, so does the directory. (I'm still learning JS at the moment).

JSON file:

```
{
    "AUD": [
        {
            "title": "Pound Australian Dollar Exchange Rate News: GBP/AUD Rallies on Risk-Averse Market",
            "media": "TorFX News",
            "date": "7 mins ago",
            "link": "https://news.torfx.com/post/2022-12-29_pound-australian-dollar-exchange-rate-news-gbp-aud-rallies-on-risk-averse-market/"
        }
      ]
}
```

HTML & JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <!----======== CSS ======== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="forex_news_container1">
        <div class="forex_news_containerAUD fxcontentNEWS">
            <div class="yooo" onclick="setCurrentLocation()" style="cursor: pointer;">
                send_to_new_page
            </div>
          
            <script>
                const requestUrl67 = 'https://api.npoint.io/b4841826d7668f639d10';
                const requestJSON67 = async url => {

                  const response67 = await (await fetch(url)).json();
                    function setCurrentLocation() {
                        var newloc = response67.AUD[0].link;
                        window.location.href = newloc;
                    }
                }
                requestJSON67(requestUrl67);
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If I were to change `response67.AUD[0].link;` to the actual link, then it works fine. Although it's not in my best interest to keep manually typing every single link for all news articles (there's a lot, this is just a snippet).

Comment: you need to parse the JSON as an Object to work in JS with it (`parse()`)

Comment: Cool, where would I have to include that? After declaring the 'Response67'?

Comment: You're calling `setCurrentLocation()` but setCurrentLocation isn't available, because it's in the scope of `requestJSON67()`. You would see an error message stating this if you look in the console.

Answer (score 0):

JS can't work directly with a JSON. You have to parse the JSON to an JS Object/Array by using the `JSON.parse()` function.

you could change your line:

```js
var newLoc = response67.AUD[0].link;
```

to this:

```js
var object = JSON.parse(response67);
var newLoc = object.AUD[0].link;
```

```js
let response = `{
  "AUD": [{
    "title": "Pound Australian Dollar Exchange Rate News: GBP/AUD Rallies on Risk-Averse Market",
    "media": "TorFX News",
    "date": "7 mins ago",
    "link": "https://news.torfx.com/post/2022-12-29_pound-australian-dollar-exchange-rate-news-gbp-aud-rallies-on-risk-averse-market/"
  }]
}`;

response = JSON.parse(response);

console.log(response.AUD[0].link);
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide an example in the JS code I have? I've replaced what you suggested but still no result unfortunately

Comment: Unfortunately not because your code is not reproducible here. I can not resolve your async function here.